# Spring Boot Data Geode Fails to Start Docker Container

Tags: dockerfile, geode, spring-data-gemfire

I am trying to setup a simple project with having 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter' in my build.gradle and now trying to dockerize the application. This runs fine locally if I run as spring boot applicaiton but the jar is not running in docker and neither any logs are coming up.

If I exclude this dependency, the docker container starts fine.

Is there something I am missing ?

```
ext {
    set('springGeodeVersion', "1.7.4")
}
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.geode:spring-geode-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Dockerfile is as simple as:

```
FROM openjdk:17-oracle
COPY build/libs/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar demo.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/demo.jar"]
```

I tried to run via WSL assuming some problem with Jar in Linux but that seems to run fine.

Comment: It seem the CPU utilization is remaining at 98 to 100%, that may be a reason for application not starting at all.

Answer (score 0):

See the [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/issues/120#issuecomment-1297844493) I left in the SBDG [Issue ticket (#120)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot-data-geode/issues/120) you filed for this problem.

I will continue the conversation there.